# awk define field pattern

Tags: bash, awk

Im looking for a way to split the following text into appropriate columns with awk.

I have

```
[2013-06-17 13:30] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -S cups'
[2013-06-17 13:30] [PACMAN] reinstalled cups (1.6.2-2)
```

So, with respect to:

```
[2013-06-17 13:30] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -S cups'
```

I would like:

```
$1 to be [2013-06-17 13:30]
$2 to be [PACMAN] 
$3 to be Running
$4 to be 'pacman -S cups'
```

for:

```
[2013-06-17 13:30] [PACMAN] reinstalled cups (1.6.2-2)
```

I would like:

```
$1 to be [2013-06-17 13:30]
$2 to be [PACMAN]
$3 to be reinstalled
$4 to be cups (1.6.2-2)
```

I've done a lot of googling, couldn't find anything and Im quite new to awk

Comment: And what about your second line? `reinstalled cups (1.6.2-2)` is to be `$3` or something else?

Comment: Show your expected output for BOTH lines and say why or we're just guessing.

Comment: Updated the output for both, I don't expect one command to cater for both scenarios

Comment: I guess a quick dirty fix would be to split on spaces, then just merge the variables I want into a new variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(What follows seems to be specific to GNU `awk`; BSD `awk` doesn't support capturing subgroups into an array.)

This is a case where you probably want to match the entire string against a specific regular expression, rather than rely on `awk`'s field splitting.

```
$ echo "[2013-06-17 13:30] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -S cups'" | awk '
    {
       match($0, "^(\\\[.*\\\]) (\\\[.*\\\]) ([a-zA-Z]*) (.*)$", a);
       $1=a[1];
       $2=a[2];
       $3=a[3];
       $4=a[4];
       print $2
    }'
[PACMAN]
```

After calling `match`, the array `a` is populated with the text from `$0` that matches the regular expression. The 0th element is the entire matching string, and the rest of the elements are set to the corresponding parenthesized groups within the regular expression.

There may be a better way to write the regular expression; I get a warning about `\[` being treated as a plain `[`, but overall it seems to work.

Comment: better way would be to enclose the regex in `/ /` instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

For an inelegant approach, see the fourth one-liner below. It works!! But you might not want to accept my answer. The command is noisy and you'd probably need to add the comments as "documentation" to make this maintainable. For that reason I've included it as an `.awk` file below as well :-)

Still, even if the format of the files is fairly simple I think the best approach is to use a regexp as @chepner notes., if only because it documents itself.

```
~/$ cat test.txt 
[2013-06-17 13:30] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -S cups'
[2013-06-17 13:30] [PACMAN] reinstalled cups (1.6.2-2)
```

**1)** Column one:

```
 ~/$ awk -F '[\]]' '{print $1"]"}' test.txt 
 [2013-06-17 13:30]
 [2013-06-17 13:30]
```

**2)** Columns one and two:

```
~/$ awk -F '[\]]' '{print $1"]" $2"]" }' test.txt 
[2013-06-17 13:30] [PACMAN]
[2013-06-17 13:30] [PACMAN]
```

**3)** All three:

```
~/$ awk -F '[\]]' '{print $1"]" $2"]"  $3}' test.txt
[2013-06-17 13:30] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -S cups'
[2013-06-17 13:30] [PACMAN] reinstalled cups (1.6.2-2)
```

**4)** Same as above, but split the third field into array `a` in order to print `Running` or `reinstalled` separately. Print a substring of array `a` (`substr`) starting at offset (`os`) taken from the `length` of the first element.

```
~/$ awk -F ']' '{split($3,a," "); os=(length(a[1])+2) ; print $1"]" $2"] " a[1]" " substr($3,os) }' test.txt
[2013-06-17 13:30] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -S cups'
[2013-06-17 13:30] [PACMAN] reinstalled cups (1.6.2-2)
```

This is BSD `awk` so it should work on OSX.

```
# split.awk ... run with: awk -f split.awk  data.txt

BEGIN{
FS="]"   # Make the field separator be "]"
}
{
  # Split the third field into array "a"
  split($3,a," ") 
  os=(length(a[1])+2) 
   # Print the first two fields and a substring of array "a" (substr)            
   # starting at offset ("os") taken from the length of the first element 
   # right adjusted for two whitespaces.
  print $1"]" $2"] " a[1]" " substr($3,os) 
}
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

there is a bit of confusion in my mind as to what you want for the 3rd and the 5th field (and the missing 4th ) as stated in your example..

1st way : 
my trial was based on introducing a new delimiter where we would like to seperate the fields...

command :

```
~/so_test> cat ztmp_bk | sed -n 's/]/]^/gp'| awk -F"^" '{print $1 "==" $2 "==" $3 }'
```

output : (fields identified by "==")

```
[2013-06-17 13:30]== [PACMAN]== Running 'pacman -S cups'
[2013-06-17 13:30]== [PACMAN]== reinstalled cups (1.6.2-2)
```

2nd way :

Alternative way would be to cut the files into parts and do it again for the 3rd file till we get the desired individual coloumn then we can merge them using paste with a user defined delimiter ...

like the following : (quite rough but you get the idea!)

```
Kaizen ~/so_test/test $ cat ztmp  | sed -n 's/]/]^/gp'| awk -F"^" '{print $1 "^" $2}' > ztmp1 ;
Kaizen ~/so_test/test $  cat ztmp  | awk -F" " '{print   $4 "^" $5 $6 $7}' > ztmp2 ;
Kaizen ~/so_test/test $  paste -d^ ztmp1 ztmp2 > ztmpF ;
```

output : this would give you a new file that is ^ delimited , hence your previous awk command will work on this file now

```
Kaizen ~/so_test/test $ cat ztmpF
[2013-06-17 13:30]^ [PACMAN]^Running^'pacman-Scups'
[2013-06-17 13:30]^ [PACMAN]^reinstalled^cups(1.6.2-2)

Kaizen ~/so_test/test $ cat ztmpF | awk -F"^" '{print "first field:" $1 "\n" "second field:" $2 "\n" "third     field:" $3 "\n" "forth field:" $4 "\n" }'
first field:[2013-06-17 13:30]
second field: [PACMAN]
third field:Running
forth field:'pacman-Scups'

first field:[2013-06-17 13:30]
second field: [PACMAN]
third field:reinstalled
forth field:cups(1.6.2-2)
```

does this help ?

Comment: @JR93 Any time you see a posted solution that uses cat and a pipe to provide input to a command that could just as easily open the file itself (e.g. `sed <script> ztmp_bk`) that's a huge red flag that the poster is very new to shell and doesn't yet understand it.

Comment: @Ed Morton , the rep points give a fair indication of the trust a community has besides i never claim i am an expert and not every one in this site is. If you disagree with the answer there is a downvote option available you can use that. Also if you have a better solution do post that ... its always good to learn new things i will give a upvote on that :)

Comment: I thought it was more useful to provide the OP (and you) with some input on how to identify prospective solutions now and in future rather than to just click the downvote button on your solution with no explanation. I also didn't think your solution warranted a downvote - until the OP tells us how to parse other lines in his input file your solution is as likely to produce the output he wants as any other.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far, but this wont help me as the file is a log file used by other software too, and copying it each time to do this seems a little unnecessary, but I guess its an option